# How to call the LAST_INSERT_ID MySQL method in PHP?

Tags: php

I have inserted a row into a MySQL table which has an automatically incremented column primary key. I want to get this primary key value through the MySQL method LAST_INSERT_ID(). So how to call it in PHP ?

Comment: The function is [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Comment: Try [mysql_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ...");

$pkValue = mysql_insert_id();
```

http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-insert-id.php